# Htaccess and watermark

Tags: php, .htaccess, watermark

I want to  know if it is possible to protect images in my host that are loaded from outside by adding a watermark using `.htaccess`?

That is, if another site uses my image URL `http://example.com/1.jpg` in a img tag in their own websites.

The plan is the when a foreign request comes to my host, I add a watermark to it and send it to the user browsing the foreign site.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with htaccess proper.  You'd have to probably redirect the user to some script (PHP, etc.) that watermarked the image.

Comment: ok i can d othis right now ! but i want to detect  foreign request comming to my host from another website !!

Comment: @bizzare    Check referer field of the request.

Comment: @bizzare You're looking to stop something called hotlinking.  Check this out:  http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess10.shtml

Comment: @Beanland yeah i was check that older , and my problem is detecting foreign request that using my image URL in his/her own img tags !

Comment: @bizzare   it is simple: RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http ://www\.yoursite\.com [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*\.(png|gif|jpg)) /your_script.php?image=$1 [NC,L]  ps: no space after http - it just breaks here )

Comment: @cheery can you show me a complete  sample please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you basically want to do, is start with this tutorial:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/hotlinking/

This shows you how to redirect images that come from external sites to a PHP page. Then, you can use that PHP page to watermark your image, with something like this:

```
<?php
header('content-type: image/jpeg');
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');
$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($watermark_width, $watermark_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['pic']);
$size = getimagesize($_GET['pic']);
$dest_x = $size[0] - $watermark_width - 5;
$dest_y = $size[1] - $watermark_height - 5;
imagecopymerge($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height, 100);
imagejpeg($image);
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($watermark);
?>
```

Comment: hummm i cant understand this part of htaccess `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !yoursite\.com [NC]` i'm working on localhost with wamp server with windows xp

Comment: @bizzare: It's a condition for this rewrite rule, you need to modify it. It basically means that the request didn't come from *your* site, that is, it's a foreign request.

Comment: you means that i must change it to my own website URL ?

Comment: ok ! is it ture ? `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !http://localhost/hotlinking [NC]`

Comment: @bizzare: Just `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !localhost [NC]` will do ("everything that's coming from localhost is fine"), but no one can hotlink you this way... You can't really test it

Comment: sorry , something wrong here ! the request do not redirect to `watermark.php` im using this line : `RewriteRule (.*) watermark.php?pic=$1`

Comment: Try `RewriteRule (.*) /watermark.php?pic=$1`. Also, how are you testing this?

Comment: i'm testing with wamp server and something work fine like when i use image URL from another place in `www` directory or with IP address the ALT tag of images appears and the image was not loaded but the watermark do not work currectly !

Comment: oh no ! i open watermark.php and it say : `can not display image because it contain some errors`

Comment: @bizzare: Perhaps you should open another question.

Answer (score 1):

The .htaccess cannot add watermarks to your images. However, it can restrict access to your images.

However, you can add watermarks using [PHP GD Library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) . The below code shows you how to add a watermark to your image through PHP GD.

```
<?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stamp.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

$stamp is the content what you want to be on watermark (eg: Copyrights Reserved) and $im is your actual image which has to be protected.

Comment: thanks men ! but this is not solve my problem ! i just want to detect foreign referer  that using my image files and then redirect it to GD enabled php file like `watermark.php`

Answer (score 0):

you must use HTTP_REFERER to determinate if user came from which link and then compare it with your own domain. if request domain was different then use php gd lib to add watermark on your images. 
you should check if HTTP_REFERER is set or not. by default if user not came from another page to your site and came directly it will be empty and not set.

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
      #check if its from external domin
      # do something here 
}
```