# Watermark via php

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, watermark

my last question is to busy so i must open a new one. (read my last question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044054/htaccess-and-watermark)).
im trying to redirect request to `watermark.php` file to embed a logo into the images that called from outside of my website. but when i use this code for htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*jpg$|.*gif$|.*png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !friendlysite\.com [NC]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !google\. [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !search\?q=cache [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) /watermark.php?pic=$1
```

and these for watermark.php :

```
<?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('tbwm.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['pic']);

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

the php file just display the alt tag of img file and return this error :
`The requested URL /watermark.php was not found on this server.` and when i open directly the watermark.php this error returns :
`The image http://192.168.1.190/hotlinking/watermark.php cont not be displayed because it contains errors.`

whats the problem ?

Comment: what do you mean with "the php file just displays the alt tag of img file"?

Comment: hum mm ,look at this : `<img src="http://localhost/1.jpg" alt="Please visit my site to see this picture">.visit w3 for more information @ `http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On a side note:**
You need to check if the image exists before outputing the image, and show a different img if not found. e.g:

```
<?php
$pathToImage='./images/'.basename($_GET['pic']);

if(file_exists($pathToImage)==true){
    // Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
    $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('tbwm.png');
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($pathToImage);

    // Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
    $marge_right = 10;
    $marge_bottom = 10;
    $sx = imagesx($stamp);
    $sy = imagesy($stamp);

    // Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo
    // width to calculate positioning of the stamp.
    imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

    // Output and free memory
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}else{
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    readfile('notfound.png');
}
?>
```

Reply to comment:

You could cache the image by adding a file name to imagepng($im, "new_image.png"); and then check if the file exists on subsequent page loads, tho it will not dramatically speed up your script but will double the amount of disk space used.

Comment: did you know that is this proccess increase performance of my website ? can i chashe watermarked images and show them later ?

Answer (score 7):

You said that : `/hotlinking/watermark.php` is your file path, so i think that your rewriterule must be

```
RewriteRule (.*) /hotlinking/watermark.php?pic=$1
```

And i think you have an error when you directly access

```
http://192.168.1.190/hotlinking/watermark.php
```

because you seems to not pass the pic parameter.

By the way :

a) i'm pretty sure that you'll have to modify the $_GET['pic'] path or the function `imagecreatefromjpeg`  won't be able to open your image.

b) if it's not a jpeg you'll have to modify it with another function. You'll have to check the image type before opening it.

--- UPDATE ---

The good RewriteRule is `RewriteRule (.*) watermark.php?pic=$1`

Now you have the watermark.php file requested. 
You must modify your code. 
$_GET['pic'] tell you what image path was requested. You'll have to modify this path to open the image.

Watermark.php is in the root dir, so maybe just a `dirname(__FILE__) . $_GET['pic']` will do.

```
    <?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$filepath = dirname(__FILE__) . $_GET['pic'];
if ( file_exists($filepath) ) 
{

    $infos = pathinfo($filepath);
    $im = null;
    switch($infos['extension']) 
    {
        case 'jpg' :
        case 'jpeg' :
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filepath);
            break,
        case 'png' : 
            $im = imagecreatefrompng($filepath);

        // ....
    }

    if ( $im !== null )
    {
        $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('tbwm.png');
        // Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
        $marge_right = 10;
        $marge_bottom = 10;
        $sx = imagesx($stamp);
        $sy = imagesy($stamp);

        // Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
        // width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
        imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

        // Output and free memory
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
}
```

This is not the full script, just how to begin. You'll have to figure out the rest by yourself.

Comment: when i use this path `RewriteRule (.*) /hotlinking/watermark.php?pic=$1` the 404 error is like this : `/hotlinking/hotlinking/watermark.php not found`

Comment: Your .htaccess is on localhost or in the "hotlinking" directory ?

Comment: ok, my mistake. `RewriteRule (.*) watermark.php?pic=$1` will do it. ( no / before the file path, or it will request for http://localhost/watermark.php )

Comment: `RewriteRule (.*) watermark.php?pic=$1` do not work ! i think the htaccess can not send image information via $_GET

Comment: i just tried on my own localhost. `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*jpg$|.*gif$|.*png$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) watermark.php?pic=$1`for the htaccess and `<?php die(var_dump($_GET['pic']))` for the watermark.php file. I requested `img/truite.jpg`( which exists ) and the result was what i expected ( string 'img/truite.jpg' ).

Comment: You should check that `$_GET['pic']` isset & is the full path to the image, unless `src="http://localhost/1.jpg"` is rootdir/1.jpg it wont be found

Comment: @DIEVarDump ok ! i test your codes and in my machine it works now , i think th GD library is broken or something like this

Comment: @bizzare ok, i updated my answer to give you more details about the path and the image type.

Comment: Hey, I was suspended, sorry for contacting you by this vía but please tell others in javascript chat room. You can contact me via contact section on live-pin.com. thanks! @DieVarDump